# Retrieve list of instance-groups an instance is a member of using gcloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, gce-instance-group

I'm using gcloud (command line) and I need to retrieve a list of instance-groups that an instance is a member of. I.e. I have the instance name and I need the instance group.

This retrieves a list of instances in a specified instance-group (but I need it the other way around):
`gcloud preview instance-groups --zone $ZONE instances --group $INSTANCE_GRP list`

Comment: This is not possible. You just need to list all instance groups.

Comment: That's annoying. I have a lot of instance groups so looping through all of them each time will be expensive. Also, I can see that the Google Cloud console displays this (in the Compute Engine list), so it shouldn't be difficult for gcloud to provide...